# today's date in the Datepicker

Tags: angular5, ngx-bootstrap

can I highlight today's date in the Datepicker?
I use Datepicker plugin in ngx-bootstrap 
On the first example of the site, it highlights the current date, but then there is no. Can i set parametr for it?

Comment: There's no such functionality for now so it's better to create feature request here https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

No, but there's an [issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/3192) to add this functionality. Alternatively you need to copy the original components and modify to your needs until it works as you want it to.